# Unable to traceroute but able to ping

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, ping

I need to connect to my own server that runs Linux Mint.

After installing Tailscale on both PCs (client and server) I can successfully ping the server from client, but I'm unable to traceroute it.

Vice-versa, from server to client everything is working smooth.
I tried checking firewalls on the server, but I'm unable to find anything that may block the connection.

I stopped the `ufw service`(that was anyway already inactive), allowed anything in and out using these `iptables` commands:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

I have no idea what may prevent the connection.

Comment: I have no firewall as far as I'm aware. I disabled all firewalls also on my router settings. I don't know what else to check. Something really odd happening.

Comment: Does the server receive any of the traceroute probes? Do you see them in the packet capture? Have you tried both UDP and ICMP traceroute modes?

Comment: No nothing arrives to the server, It fails with a !H error. Yes i tried every mode.

Comment: Are there are two subnets involved ? ([link](https://tailscale.com/kb/1214/site-to-site/))